# Onchange Event in Javascript; How to input diffrent items

Tags: javascript, html

I am fairly new to javascript and I am 13. So I am new to events in javascript. I would like help on this code:

```
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementById("fname");
if (x=="Kyle")
{
document.write("Correct!");
}
else
{
document.write("Incorrect!")
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onchange="myFunction()">
</body>
```

I want it to say correct when I type my name. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. Those days are over. Use the DOM.

Comment: This is an off-topic comment, I know... but keep it up man. I love seeing young kids get into development. It tends to breed the type of devs you see here on SO: the ones with a passion for it. I started when I was 11 and haven't looked back since. At least you have the powerof SO to lean on :)

Comment: did my reply solve your second problem?

Answer (score 2):

the line

```
if (x=="Kyle")
```

should read

```
if (x.value=="Kyle")
```

x represents the element, not the element's value.

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask if you have any other problems.

---

First create a div tag below your form and give it an id of something like "messageBox"

so:

```
<div id="messageBox"></div>
```

then replace

```
document.write("Correct!");
```

with

```
document.getElementById('messageBox').innerHTML = "Correct!";
```

and the same for incorrect.

All this does is create a div tag so that the javascript has somewhere to output the success/failure message.

Comment: I also have another problem. How am I able to display it on the same page. I want correct or incorrect below it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you an example of how to approach the problem.

Comment: Peter your answered has helped me! Also thank you to Jason L. You will not see the last of me! (Mostly because I still have a lot to learn)

Answer (score 1):

You were oh so very close.  You get the DOM element (getElementById), but you need to get the actual value of the element.  Use `x.value == "Kyle"`

Comment: Thanks to all that posted! You were all helpful